# jQuery hit enter to submit the current form on page with multiple forms?

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a page with multiple forms and was wondering if there was any examples showing how to submit the current form you filled in when hitting enter?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Submit the closest form

```
$("element").closest("form").submit();
```

You have to add an event `keydown` and submit the closest form:

```
$("input[type=text]") // retrieve all inputs
    .keydown(function(e) { // bind keydown on all inputs
        if (e.keyCode == 13) // enter was pressed
            $(this).closest("form").submit(); // submit the current form
    });
```

See [closest on jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of browsers, when hitting enter while inside a form element, is to submit the form that the element belongs to ..

So you have nothing to worry about, unless i am misunderstanding the question ..

Comment: yes I had the form input set as button not submit so it wasnt working. Plus the button is linked to a ajax function so I used .submit() and just returned false in th function to stop the form submitting. Thanks guys